# Is there a word for words formed of repeating sounds?

Tags: single-word-requests, reduplication

Is there a word for words formed of repeating sounds?

Mama, Papa, ... Any other such words...

Comment: A very general term is  [Reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication)  "*Reduplication in linguistics is a morphological process in which the root or stem of a word (or part of it) or even the whole word is repeated exactly or with a slight change.*"

Comment: Related: 1. [What is the origin of 'fuddy-duddy'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425192/what-is-the-origin-of-fuddy-duddy), 2. [What is the origin of the phrase “hunky dory”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-hunky-dory) 3. [“Josephine, Schmosephine”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379805/josephine-schmosephine)

Comment: [Term for words like “Hanky-Panky”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247896/term-for-words-like-hanky-panky)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinctive linguistic feature in words like *papa, dada, mama* or *bubba* is called [*reduplication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication#English), or to be precise, exact reduplication, where a single CV syllable is repeated.

When infants begin to vocalize beyond crying, they imitate the prosody of the language around them with vowel sounds. When they are a bit older, a limited set of consonants — usually stops and nasals — combine with the vowel sounds into [babbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babbling), a word imitative of infant sounds like bababa. This repetition is called canonical or reduplicative babbling, which in turn is imitated in [baby talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk), or child directed speech (CDS), in a limited set of English words. Think of it as a kind of pidgin language between adults and children, which like any language, can preserve archaic features. Generations of children were taught the word *choo choo* ‘train’ long after trains were no longer steam-powered with whistles.

This feature of baby talk seems a peculiarity of English. Italian has a more limited set, but *il papa* is the name for the Pope, so I guess it balances out. Languages with highly productive diminutives, like Czech/Slovak *-ko*, tend to use those. The German CDS word for ‘doggy’, for example, is a double diminutive: *Hund* + *i* + *lein*, [*Hundilein*](https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/deutsch-englisch/Hundilein.html) ‘little doggy’.

This feature is productive in adult speech as well, with some baby talk borrowing:

**Exact reduplication**: *bye bye, hush hush, toot toot, too too* (as in *too too much*), *la la, so so, gaga, beebee, papa, dada, mama,   bubba* (brother), *wakey wakey*. Words imitative of laughter or giggling: *hee hee, ha ha, ho ho.* With infix: *yackity yack*. *Yada yada yada* and *blah blah blah* would be triplication, I suppose.

**Rhyming reduplication** occurs when only an initial consonant changes or is added: *teeny weeny, super duper, willy nilly, boogie woogie, walkie talkie, bow wow, argle bargle, hodgepodge/hotchpotch*. *Tra la la* would be triplication. [*Ragtag*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ragtag) was formed from two “normal” lexemes, but fits the pattern. Brand names like TicTac candies or the Southern American grocery store chain Piggly Wiggly.

A subtype of rhyming reduplication is [**shm-reduplication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication) borrowed from Yiddish: fancy shmancy. This feature, [combined in Eastern Yiddish](https://www.academia.edu/209796/Metalinguistic_shmetalinguistic_The_phonology_of_shm-reduplication) from two features in Slavic and Turkic languages, spread from New York City to the rest of the US by the 1930s.

**Ablaut reduplication** occurs when a vowel is changed, almost always from a front vowel to a mid or back one: *teeny tiny, shilly shally, dilly dally, hiphop, zigzag, seesaw, singsong, pitter patter, splish splash, mishmash, ping pong, tick tock, flipflop, riff raff.* In the American South, *mamaw* and *papaw* ‘grandmother’, ‘grandfather’. With infix: *tickity tock, clickity clack*. *Telltale* isn’t formed as these words, but fits the phonetic pattern.

Another linguistic feature sometimes termed [contrastive focus reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_focus_reduplication) is where a word is repeated, the first instance establishing a meaning as ‘true to type’ or as ‘commony understood’ as opposed to some other sense.

> This was in Delano, CA I was visiting my girlfriend (friend friend no relationship just a girl friend I'm a guy so that's ok to have a girl girl friend).

Though a bit confusing, this writer is insisting that the constituent parts of *girlfriend* be understood in their non-compounded senses: a friend friend (no romantic involvement) and a girl girl, a young woman (with whom he has no romantic relationship).

Comment: I normally love your answers, and this is no different but [reduplicative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/199928/44619) and reduplication have been given as [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/358379/44619) many times in the past.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: True, but I doubt if those answers include all the features I discuss. I could have thrown in how my attempt at pronouncing _great grandmother_ at the age of two became _Googaa_, which became her nickname, but thought that would make the answer too long.

Comment: How is "bubba", exact reduplication?

Comment: @Malandy: because it is, as a large number of Southerners would pronounce it (buhbuh). A broader accent can lengthen the first vowel in mamma or bubba with a glide.

Answer (score -2):

Yes: assonance. Assonance is repeating vowel sounds, as in your example. A repeating consonant sound in the middle or at the end of a word is known as 'consonance'. Of course, most are familiar with 'alliteration': repeating sounds at the beginning of words, but that is not what you are asking.

Comment: The original post did not ask about syllables. It asked about repeating sounds. The repeating 'a' s in 'Mama' and 'Papa' create an aural effect. The answer is not wrong.